# SpringBoot Security ldap auth against multiple separate AD domains

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to have SpringBoot use multiple AD authentication providers against different domains?

So, like I have two separate AD controllers

```
URL: ldap://ad.region1.company.com
baseDN: dc=region1,dc=company,dc=com
```

and

```
URL: ldap://ad.region2.company.com
baseDN: dc=region2,dc=company,dc=com
```

And some code like:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapdomain, ldapurl);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    return provider;
}
```

Where ldapdomain and ldapurl are set to the "region1" values. I also want to be able to authenticate "region2" users. Is there some way to provide both endpoints and have it try both? Or a way to provide a hint in the login on which one to use?

Comment: Any answer on this? I have the same problem. I can connect to different LDAP servers but I need to set multiple baseDN.

Comment: @JimmyD Unfortunately no. I ended up just writing the logic in plain Java and generated a JWT. Then used HandlerInterceptorAdapter to intercept the requests and make sure they had a token.

Answer (score 0):

Defile like below mention. Space should be mandatory between two urls.

```
String ldapdomain = "ldap://ad.region1.company.com ldap://ad.region2.company.com"
```

Comment: What about urls ? should they be space-separated ? or comma separated ?